# Visual Studio 2015 C# does not update references properly?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

We are currently suffering problem with not updated reference in our projects.

For example:
We change one of our libraries - `Cars`, we add method `GetCarType()` to one of its classes. Then we use this method in another library - `ParkingPlace`. It is nicely compilable. But when we compile it and use it, typically as plugin, we get exception telling "*method GetCarType() not found*". We can solve problem by manually removing reference to the `Cars` library from `ParkingPlace` project and adding it back. Now when we build ParkingPlace and use it, everything is fine. I have never experience issue like that, but it is kind of random and it brings me lot of pain.

Does anyone know this issue? By what it is cause? Or how to solve it?

Thanks in regards.

Comment: Are you sure you don't add reference to release dll and build in debug?

Comment: Check the date/time stamp of the DLL(s) that you *think* you are building.  Make sure they show the same date/time as your computer's clock (check right after the build).

Comment: Check configuration manager - maybe yo do not have some of the projects active. Then automatic compile/copy "breaks". Well, breaks is maybe a bad word because "you ask for those projects not to be processed".

Comment: @AlexanderDerck Yes, I am sure.

Comment: @RoberHarvey time stamp is correct. That was first I checked.

Comment: @TomTom what you mean by "active"? Maybe I should mention that this issue has kind of random nature. Once it happens, next time does not.